# Раскладка клавиатуры в Docker на OSX некорректна при использовании Selenium SendKeys

Tags: java, google-chrome, macos, selenium, docker

Проблема в следующем. Пишу тесты на *Java*, использую *Selenium* и *Chrome*, для разработки использую *OSx*.

При локальном запуске тестов проблем нет. Но когда я решил перенести запуск тестов в Докер - произошла странная вещь. Все тесты, в которых не используются Input проходят нормально. А при использовании `sendKeys` текст, в поля вводится не полностью. Символ E работает как Backspace, при передаче R - символ просто пропускается. Такое ощущение, как будто раскладка клавиатуры изменена.

При запуске таким же образом в Докере на *Linux* машине - все отлично. 
Подскажите куда копать, возможно кто-то сталкивался с этим.

- Docker 18.03
- Chrome 63
- ChromeDriver 2.38